# Unable to unit test a class which calls an API

Tags: unit-testing, junit, mockito

I have the following two classes -

Service class

```
@Service
public class ProfileInfoCacheService {

    public ProfileInfoResponse getProfileInfo(String uuid) {

            ProfileInfoResponse response = getUserInfoFromIdentity(uuid);
            return response;

    }

public ProfileInfoResponse getUserInfoFromIdentity(String identity) {
        LinkedHashMap<String, List<UserInfo>> profileInfo = userService.getUserInfoFromIdentity(identityList);

        return profcache.getProfileInfo();

    }
```

And component

```
@Component
public class UserInfoServiceImpl implements UserInfoService {

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public LinkedHashMap<String, List<UserInfo>> getUserInfoFromIdentity(List<String> identityList) {
        //Calls an API and returns data in LinkedHashMap.
    }
```

Now, here is my test case file. Please bear with me as I am still new at it.

```
package com.citruspay.prepaid;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

//class file imports

import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ProfileInfoCacheServiceTest {

    private PrepaidAccount account;
    private ProfileInfoCacheService pics;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        account = new PrepaidAccount("8588844251");
        //pics = new ProfileInfoCacheService();
        ProfileInfoCacheService pics = mock(ProfileInfoCacheService.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void testConstructor() {
        assertEquals("8588888888", account.owner());
    }

    @Test
    public void testNumber() throws Exception {
        ProfileInfoResponse response = pics.getProfileInfo("7266704751953077361"); //pics is null here

        assertEquals("", response.getEmail() );
        assertEquals("8588888888", response.getMobile() );
    }
}
```

The response of getProfileInfo() call is expected to be in this format -

```
{
        "email": "some.email@something.in",
        "mobile": "8888888888",
    }
```

Every mobile/email pair has a number (like 7266704751953077361), using which, when the API is called, it returns the same.

However, I am getting a Null Pointer exception, due to pics being null where I call pics.getProfileInfo("7266704751953077361").

Please help me correct my mistake here.

**Update**

Upon changing mock() to new class call, I get the ProfileInfoCacheService object but then on moving the debug to the last line of the setup() method, getting the following -

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.<init>(StaticLoggerBinder.java:72)
    at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.<clinit>(StaticLoggerBinder.java:45)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:150)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:124)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:412)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:357)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:383)
    at com.citruspay.prepaid.common.user.beans.ProfileInfoCacheService.<init>(ProfileInfoCacheService.java:42)
    at com.citruspay.prepaid.ProfileInfoCacheServiceTest.setUp(ProfileInfoCacheServiceTest.java:26)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.run(JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.java:37)
    at org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:62)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Detected both log4j-over-slf4j.jar AND bound slf4j-log4j12.jar on the class path, preempting StackOverflowError. See also http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#log4jDelegationLoop for more details.
    at org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory.<clinit>(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:54)
    ... 33 more
```

**Update 2**

Adding more details of ProfileInfoCacheService class -

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisException;

import com.aerospike.client.AerospikeException;
import com.aerospike.client.Key;
import com.citruspay.prepaid.common.cache.dao.ProfileInfoCacheDao;
import com.citruspay.prepaid.common.cache.entity.ProfileInfoCache;
import com.citruspay.prepaid.common.cache.factory.DaoCacheFactory;
import com.citruspay.prepaid.common.user.process.UserInfoServiceImpl;
import com.spikeify.ResultSet;
@Service
public class ProfileInfoCacheService {

    @Autowired
    UserInfoServiceImpl userService;

    @Autowired 
    DaoCacheFactory<ProfileInfoCacheDao> daoCacheFactory;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        ProfileInfoCacheDao profileInfoCacheDao = daoCacheFactory.getDaoForRead(ProfileInfoCacheDao.class);
        profileInfoCacheDao.init();
    }

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ProfileInfoCacheService.class);
```

Comment: From your test it doesn't seem like you're initializing the field `pics`, hence the `NPE` when trying to call a method on it. Looking at your setup method seems like you're going to try and mock it. You shouldn't mock the things you're testing, but rather their dependencies.

Comment: The same as in a `NPE`? could you add the code for `getProfileInfo`? Maybe even the entire class plus the exception traceback please?

Comment: Thanks! changed that, however, now getting an object on debugging, but on moving to the end of setup(), I get a ExceptionInInitializerError

Comment: Added the exception details. Let me know if you need anything else. The class structure/hierarchy, with reference to the specific method is already added.

Comment: To me just looks like inside `ProfileInfoCacheService` you have a dependency on log4j which fails to initialize when running in unit tests. I don't use log4j on a daily basis, but on Android I faced a similar problem and wrote a wrapper around the logger that can be mocked/configured at unit test time. Maybe log4j supports this out of the box.

Comment: Could you please elaborate with an example here? I have added more details into the dependency on LoggerFactory class.

Comment: Unrequested suggestion: make your correct rather than a spring mess. On `ProfileInfoCacheService` create a constructor that receives the 2 dependencies and set up anything that needs setup. Unit tests should test a class in complete isolation, without any Spring mess.

Comment: Did you check your classpath as the exception asked you to? What is the reason you have both these jar's in your dependencies for your tests? -- If I understand correctly you're not using mockito anymore, so you might want to edit you question (and remove the now unrelated parts) to make that point clearer.